# Google Calendar - calendar visibility and groupings

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, visibility

When using Google Calendar in Chrome, there is a 'Display this only' option that will hide all my calendars apart from the selected calendar. I have a list of about 20 calendars so this feature is very useful.

The problem is that to re-enable the visibility of the other 19 calendars, I have to click on each calendar's checkbox (in the left sidebar), one at a time. This is not at all practical when needed a less complicated view for dealing with many events in each of the calendars.

Ideally, what I would like is to have the ability to turn on the visibility of all calendars with one click, but also to group calendars so that I can show and hide groups of calendars with one click. This would work really well with Room and Resource calendars.

I understand that users have been requesting that Calendar natively support these types of features for over 10 years now. From the lack of response on this issue from Google, it seems they don't think this is worth adding, which surprises me considering half of the feature is there with the 'Display this only' option.

So, does anyone know of a way to create visibility groups (or all calendars shown/hidden with a click) programmatically? Maybe with Google App Script? I would appreciate anything that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe try [getAllCalendars()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getallcalendars) or [getAllOwnedCalendars()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getallownedcalendars) to list all calendars; followed by the `setSelected` **boolean** value.